# partial fractions for a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I need help finding the partial fraction decomposition for this function, I am just lost on it, here it is:
$(x^2 + x + 1)/(2x^4+3x^2+1)$. the help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: $$\dfrac{2 x+1}{2 x^2+1}-\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: can you please post your work, cuz am getting stuck somewhere

Comment: **Hint:** $$2x^4+3x^2+1 =  \left(2 x^2+1\right) \left(x^2+1\right)$$

Comment: yes I have that already, but am getting stuck on finding the values of the constants, am getting no solution for my matrix to find the values of the constants

Comment: Write it as $$\dfrac{a x+b}{2 x^2+1} + \dfrac{c x + d}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: well that is what i did, and not getting the right answer

Comment: Well, maybe add the details to the question so we can see where you are are erring. You can cross multiply and equate terms and arrive at a system.

Comment: i can't unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The key to it is how to factor the denominator $2x^4+3x^2+1$. Denote $y=x^2$ and you're left with a quadratic $2y^2+3y+1$ whose roots are $-1$ and $-1/2$. So

$$2x^4+3x^2+1=(y+1)(2y+1)=(x^2+1)(2x^2+1)$$

Now we're looking for

$${x^2+x+1\over 2x^4+3x^2+1}={ax+b\over x^2+1}+{cx+d\over 2x^2+1}$$

Multiply both sides by $x^2+1$ and substitute $x=i$ to get

$${i\over -1}=ai+b$$

and so $a=-1$ and $b=0$

Multiply both sides by $2x^2+1$ and substitute $x=i/\sqrt{2}$ to get

$${-{1\over 2}+{i\over\sqrt{2}}+1\over -{1\over 2}+1}=c{i\over\sqrt{2}}+d\iff {2i\over\sqrt{2}}+1=c{i\over\sqrt{2}}+d$$

and this yields $c=2$ and $d=1$ and so

$${x^2+x+1\over 2x^4+3x^2+1}={2x+1\over 2x^2+1}-{x\over x^2+1}$$

Comment: that is really interesting, cuz am getting no solution for my matrix to find the values of the constants. you way greatly works. but can you elaborate on how you determined to use complex number i

Comment: $i$ is a root of $x^2+1$ and $i/\sqrt{2}$ a root of $2x^2+1$. The interesting part with complex roots is that with one substitution you determine two real coefficients where you would have needed two real substitutions.

Comment: thank you for your insight, I appreciate your help, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by one user.

$\frac{(x^2 + x + 1)}{(2x^4+3x^2+1)} = \frac{ax+b}{2x^2+1} + \frac{cx+d}{x^2+1}$

$x^2+x+1 = (ax+b)(x^2+1) + (cx+d)(2x^2+1)$

Comparing terms containing $x^3$,

$0 = a + 2c$

Comparing terms containing $x^2$,

$1 = b + 2d$

Comparing terms containing $x$,

$1 = a + c$

Comparing terms containing constant terms,

$1 = b + d$

Hope you can solve above equations to find a, b, c and d.

Comment: I see where my mistake is, thank you for your help

Comment: Your welcome...